# Spring Batch Issue with chunk size 20

Tags: spring, size, chunks

Having issue when trying to increase the chunk size from 1 to 20.
Used the Skip listeners and when its skipping the record in a chunk lets says 10th record its skips then after that all records will have issue saying that "ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block" and rest of the records in Process will be failed.

But when I make the chunk size as 1 it works fine, please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Configuration:

```
return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<***, Object> chunk(20)
                .reader(*****)
                .processor(****)
                .writer(*****)
                .faultTolerant()
                .skip(NullPointerException.class)
                .skip(NumberFormatException.class)
                .skip(PersistenceException.class)
                .skip(DataException.class)
                .noRetry(DataException.class)
                .noRetry(PersistenceException.class)
                .noRollback(DataException.class)
                .noRollback(PersistenceException.class)
                .noSkip(InternalServerErrorException.class)
                .noSkip(IntegrationServiceException.class)
                .skipLimit(9999999)
                .listener(*****)
                .build();
```

Tech details:

> spring.framework.version 4.1.7.RELEASE
>
> spring.batch.version 3.0.6.RELEASE
>
> Java 1.8

Comment: Tech Details:spring-framework-version -4.1.7.RELEASE
  spring-batch-version -3.0.6.RELEASE